# How to insert a new node to list in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, collections, jpql

Ok. Lets say I have this:

```
class Dog{
String name;
List<Leg> legs;
//get and set
}

class Leg{
float lenght;
}
```

To add a new leg to a dog (lets say it has 3):
1-Query this: Select d from Dog d join d.legs where d.id = 1
2-After I have the dog reference then I add a new Leg to the list:
dog.getLegs().add(new Leg(3.9));

3-Merge the dog.: em.merge(dog);

Is this the only way for updating collections? I just wonder if the dog instance occupies unnecessary heap space. 
Thank you Java PROS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about performance then you could always define a bidirectional relationship between the entities and then manage it from the other end.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dog")
public class Dog {
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "dog_legs", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "dog_id", unique = true) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "leg_id") })
    private Set<Leg> legs;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "legs")
public class Leg {
    private Integer length;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="legs")
    private Dog dog;
}
```

With this bidirectional mapping you can save a Dog leg with just the cost of loading the Dog object.

```
Dog d = entityManager.find(Dog.class, Long.valueOf(1));
Leg l = new Leg();
l.setDog(d);
l = entityManager.persist(l);
```

Comment: Bid Mapping is an easy way to get thru this, but I'm not agree with use it but when is really required. Is this the only alternative to load the entire dog?

Comment: Are you looking for a hard way? You could always flatten your object attributes and map JDBC manually.

Comment: No man, I Just look bid mapping like increase dependecies in my OOP Desing :S, doesnt it?